# Git moving changes from one local repository to another local repository

Tags: git

I have a local git repository called "web" which is a clone of a remote (origin) repository.  I pull from that repo to keep web up to date and when I do git diff origin/master my copy has not diverged from the origin.

However I also have another local repository called "web2" which is my original copy of the remote repository (origin). This old version is also linked to origin and I can do a pull to get the latest changes from the remote.  Web2 has all my old commit history but has diverged significantly from origin.

I would like to do some work on my old web2 version and only move those changes/patches to the cloned "Web" version so when I do a push from Web, I am not bringing obsolete files and code to the remote.  The other developer pulls from origin too so potentially I can create a lot of problems.

So is it possible to work on my old web2 version then fetch only those changes into web without pulling or merging and bringing outdated code to web which should be clean for upstream?

Or would it be better if I created a "test" branch from Web then merge JUST the differences to Web (master) therefore not having to work on the old Web2 version at all?

Comment: Try to use only one repo, and maybe keep the different work streams in separate branches. You will be able to merge/cherry-pick changes this way, and you only have to deal with one repo.

Comment: @nwinkler: the only thing that makes sense. I know people with a similar setup but they have a hard job keeping track of which changes did they do in which repo...

Answer (score 0):

Try using git fetch/rebase in your web2 directory to insert all the commits from the remote into your local branch then you can easilly push to the remote branch with no conflicts

Comment: I can already pull from the remote into my Web2 to get all the latest remote commits.  I'm more interested in using Web2 as a testbed repo and when I build something useful, I move those to Web and only commit THOSE changes in Web for upstream to the remote origin.

Comment: You could select the commits you want to push using rebase -i to sort them out then push "commit number" but using 2 different repos will certainly lead to conflicts when pushing on the remote branch.